# GNU ld produces ELF with no symbols when static library is used

Tags: gcc, linker, symbols, gnu, ld

I am trying to pack multiple object files into `ar` archive and then pass the archive to the linker.

My C source file `foo.c` contains this line:

```
void foo();
```

When it is compiled using `gcc -c foo.c`, it the resulting object file contains this symbol:

```
$ nm foo.o
0000000000000000 T foo
```

Then I archive it:

```
$ ar rcs foo.a foo.o
```

The archive now contains the file `foo.o` with the same symbol:

```
$ nm foo.a
foo.o:
0000000000000000 T foo
```

But linked ELF contains no symbol named `foo`:

```
$ ld foo.a
$ nm a.out
0000000000401000 A __bss_start
0000000000401000 A _edata
0000000000401000 A _end
                 U _start
```

Why is it not there?

I want to use this approach because I am producing multiple executable file variants with one common part (one archive, not shown for simplicity) and second part containing `main` symbol (the object files in `foo.a`).

Comment: Static libraries are linked as follows. When the linker sees a static library, it takes the set of *symbols unresolved so far*, and looks each such symbol up in the library. Only objects that resolve these symbols are included in the final binary.

Comment: Can I force it somehow to keep all symbols from the static library?

Comment: Yes, for gnu ld it's `--whole-archive`.

Comment: Would you add it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static libraries are normally linked as follows. When the linker sees a static library, it takes the set of symbols unresolved so far, and looks each such symbol up in the library. Only objects that resolve these symbols are included in the final binary.

To override this behaviour, `gnu ld` has a switch `--whole-archive`. From the man page:

> For each archive mentioned on the command line after the `--whole-archive`
> option, include every object file in the archive in the link, rather than searching the archive for the required object files. This is normally used to turn an archive file into a
> shared library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting
> shared library.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `ld` flag `--whole-archive`:

```
$ ld --whole-archive foo.a
```